# Solving differential equation using finitie difference method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been sitting few hours trying to solve this equation (using finite difference method):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left([\cos(2\pi x)+1]\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right) = 0  $$

$$x \in[0,1]$$

$$\frac{du(0)}{dx}+u(0)=1$$

$$ u(1)=0  $$

So this is my way of thinking:

I assume $k=[\cos(2\pi x)+1]$ and get $(ku')'=0$ and then I get $k_i 'u_i ' +k_i u_i''=0$ and then afer doing some transformations I get :

$$k_iu_{i-1}+(-k_i-k_{i+1})u_i+k_{i+1}u_{i+1}=0$$

I also know (from the third equation) that $u_1-(1-h)u_0=h$

Moreover I can define $k_i$ as $k_i =[\cos(2\pi x_i)+1]$ where $x_i=x_0+i\times h$ and $x_0 = 0$

I am also sure that $h=\dfrac{1}{N}$ (because I am dividing $(0,1)$ to $N$ elements)

Let's assumme I am taking $N=4$ points.
My $h=0.25$

So I got the matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.75 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
        1 & -1 & 0 & 0&0& \\
        0 & 0 & -1 & 1&0& \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & -3&2& \\
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0&1& \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
        u_0 \\
        u_1 \\
        u_2  \\
        u_3  \\
       u_4  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        0.25 \\
        0 \\
        0  \\
        0  \\
       0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

After solving I got:

\begin{cases}
u_0 = 1\\ 
u_1 = 1\\ 
u_2 = 0\\
u_3 = 0\\
u_4 =0
\end{cases}

Which result in $u_i(x)$ graph:

[image: N=4]

But when I get $N=50$:

[image]

This plots just does not seem correct. (This equation I have to solve is somehow connected to of heat transportation)

I will be very glad if someone would tell me what am I doing wrong. I am newbie at solving differential equations and need assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that when $x=1/2$ the diffusion coefficient $\cos(2\,\pi\,x)+1$ vanishes. This means that there is no connection between what happens in $[0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1]$. What you observe is thus reasonable.

The equation can be solved explicitly. The general solution is
$$
u=C_1\tan(\pi\, x)+C_2,\quad C_i\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
It has a singularity at $x=1/2$, as expected. Imposing the boundary conditions, the solution would be
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}
a\,(\tan(\pi\,x) -\pi)+1 & 0\le x<1/2,\\
b\tan(\pi\,x)  & 1/2< x\le1
\end{cases},\quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$$
The only regular solution is $u=0$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if I want to solve this using finite difference method I should separately solve this for $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ ?

Comment: What should I do in my algorithm to make this work? Avoid this point?

Comment: I believe that finite differences will not see the singularity at $x=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I am not quite sure if i understand you correctly. I understand that when I hit the $x=1/2$ my diffusion coefficient is zeroing and my whole algorithm is collapsing. I want to solve this equation using finite difference method but it fails when i hit this critical point and I get bad results (plots shown above). My question is: what I can do to make this algorithm work? (I clueless what to do to be honest) and what do you mean by saying that finite difference will not see the singularity?

Comment: I would suggests chanching the difussion coeficiente to $k+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ small.